Setting a value for max_locks_per_transaction
We find ourselves in a situation where we need to increase the value max_locks_per_transaction as the default isn't appropriate. I've spent some time looking and I can't find any information to suggest how to set this value, is it just a case of trial and error?
Thanks in advance

How many locks do you need? If you don't know, it is trial and error.

I had this problem years ago.  PH developers said that mlpt can be a million or more without impact.  Thus, i set it to 15360 (15Ki).

The size of the lock table is slightly bigger than max_connections * max_locks_per_transaction. So if you know how many locks you need, it is easy to find a good value for max_locks_per_transaction.
You typically need one lock per table in an SQL statement — if partitioned tables are involved, you need one lock for each partition. If you need to handle n concurrent statements, multiply the number by n.
If you cannot guess a good value, try doubling the size until the error goes away. It doesn't matter if you set the value too high; the amount of memory needed is negligible on modern machines.
